# Trying to use pyinstaller with skyfield, building .exe but failing to run

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, skyfield

I am trying to package up a script with pyinstaller that uses the skyfield module/API, and it builds, but when I run it, it dies saying it can't find `nutation.npz` (a data file included in the `nutationlib.py`     `_arrays = load_bundled_npy('nutation.npz')` ).

I have tried using `--onefile`, not using it. `--add-data` and `--add-binary` don't like it. `--hidden-imports` doesn't help. `--debug=imports` wasn't too useful, but the attached log was from `--debug=all` compilation.

Any thoughts on how to force pyinstaller to include nutation.npz into the built .exe so its there when its extracted/run?

```
import skyfield.nutationlib # PyInstaller PYZ
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "satvis.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\fox\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\skyfield\api.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\fox\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\skyfield\constellationlib.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\fox\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\skyfield\timelib.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\fox\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\skyfield\nutationlib.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "site-packages\skyfield\functions.py", line 143, in load_bundled_npy
  File "pkgutil.py", line 637, in get_data
  File "c:\users\fox\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 471, in get_data
    with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\fox\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI89762\\skyfield\\data\\nutation.npz'
[44412] Failed to execute script satvis
```

Comment: Did you move the .exe file from the folder which is generated by the pyinstaller

Comment: Nope. both the --onefile and not onefile ones were run where they built

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a directory with `skyfield` data files (npz, npy, etc).

For example, if `skyfield` located in the virtual environment folder, you need the following `pyinstaller` call:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data 'venv/Lib/site-packages/skyfield/data;skyfield/data' yourapp.py
```

Answer (score 0):

In Skyfield's code, it looks like it thinks of that file as belonging to the package "skyfield":

```
data = get_data('skyfield', 'data/{0}'.format(filename))
```

But in Skyfield's `setup.py`, that file belongs to the subpackage `skyfield.data` instead:

```
package_data = {
    'skyfield': ['documentation/*.rst'],
    'skyfield.data': ['Leap_Second.dat', 'deltat.data', 'deltat.preds',
                      '*.npy', '*.npz'],
    'skyfield.tests': ['data/*'],
    },
```

If you have the ability to edit your local copy of Skyfield, try changing the above-quoted line of code from `skyfield/functions.py` so that it says:

```
data = get_data('skyfield.data', '{0}'.format(filename))
```

There is some chance that the change will fix the problem with PyInstaller. If it does, I will make the change officially to Skyfield’s code!

Comment: I tried:data = get_data('skyfield.data', '{0}'.format(filename)) and data = get_data('skyfield.data', 'data/{0}'.format(filename))  No dice.   Same can't find it with the --onefile. However, I can manually create the skyfield/data directories in the dist folder when not using --onefile and put all of the data files in there manually and it then runs, but just would be nice to not have to do that.

Comment: Alas! I had hoped that would work. Skyfield lists the file in both its `setup.py` and `MANIFEST`, so as far as I know there are no additional places where I can add it. If I think of anything else to try I’ll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build a working "onefile" of myprog.exe on Win10 with

python 3.7.9
pyinstaller 4.0
skyfield 1.29

by building a spec file using the command

```
pyinstaller -F myprog.py
```

then in the spec file, changing the line

```
datas=[],
```

to

```
datas=[ ('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\skyfield-1.28-pyh9f0ad1d_0\\site-packages\\*', 'skyfield')],
```

The build command I used was

```
pyinstaller -clean myprog.spec
```

I don't believe Anaconda had anything to do with it, that's just where my installation has the skyfield package data. I did build it in a standard Python virtual environment however.